# Cannot install Mariadb on Linux Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mariadb

I would like to install Mariadb on Ubuntu 20.04. I followed instructions on download page.

Here is what I get.

```
joe@joeslinux:~$ curl -LsS https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup | sudo bash
[sudo] password for joe: 
[info] Repository file successfully written to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mariadb.list
[info] Adding trusted package signing keys...
[info] Running apt-get update...
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/zanchey/asciinema/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://ocean.surfshark.com/debian stretch InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1DB7590E83C8F643 Surfshark package maintainer <admin@surfshark.com>
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 78BD65473CB3BD13
E: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release' is not signed.
[error] Failed to add trusted package signing keys
joe@joeslinux:~$
```

I notice it's balking at something to do with Surfshark. Yes, I have surfshark vpn running.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if problem with Mariadb installation is related with surfshark (I don't check MariaDB installation script, but probably it's fail when apt fail).

But,
GPG keys for surfshark repo  was changed. Go to official surfshark website, and download new deb package. This package install repo and public keys, not surfshark itself.